# Run python wtih flask in docker returns ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

Tags: python, docker, flask

I'm running python in docker and run across the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'` error message. any thoughts what am I missing in the Dockerfile or requirements ?

```sh
FROM python:3.7.2-alpine

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN apk update && \
        apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python-dev 

RUN adduser -D myuser
USER myuser
WORKDIR /home/myuser
COPY --chown=myuser:myuser ./requirements.txt /home/myuser/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --user -r requirements.txt

ENV PATH="/home/myuser/.local/bin:${PATH}"

COPY --chown=myuser:myuser . .

ENV FLASK_APP=/home/myuser/app.py

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
~
```

in the app.py I use this line

```sh
from flask import Flask, jsonify
```

with requirements looking like this

```sh
Flask==0.12.5
```

Comment: I don't see flask being installed with pip in the Dockerfile.

Comment: int's in this line RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --user -r requirements.txt

Comment: flask is installed in your user dir, but is that path to the flask module visible to python?

Comment: I suspect about this line `COPY --chown=myuser:myuser ./requirements.txt /home/myuser/requirements.txt` it should be `COPY --chown=myuser:myuser requirements.txt /home/myuser/requirements.txt` and better to rebuild docker image

Answer (score 0):

You can verify if the packages were properly installed with

`docker exec <container ID> pip list`

Answer (score 0):

1. I've selected **slim** container to remove need to install build-deps etc
2. use `docker-compose` to pull it together `/htpc` as *root* dir.  `static` is served directly from nginx container

```
FROM python:3-slim
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV FLASK_APP app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST 0.0.0.0
USER $UNAME
COPY requirements.txt /htpc/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /htpc
RUN echo "install python packages" && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD python app.py
```

```
  htpc:
    container_name: htpc
    environment:
      - PUID=${PUID} # default user id, defined in .env 
      - PGID=${PGID} # default group id, defined in .env
      - TZ=${TZ} # timezone, defined in .env
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: flask-Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/htpc
    networks:
      - htpc-network
    ports: 
      - "5000:5000"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes: 
      - ../app.py:/htpc/app.py
      - ../mc:/htpc/mc
      - ../templates:/htpc/templates
```